# How can I randomize all lines in a TextBox?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, random

I want to randomize all lines in `TextBox.Text`.

But my code is randomizing the values in the array `myStrings()` only. What I want to do is randomize all lines in `TextBox.Text`.

Here's my code:

```
Dim myRnd as New Random
Dim myStrings() As String  = {dfasdht,agaskhga,twrtwert}

Textbox1.Text = myStrings(myRnd.Next(3))
```

Here's an example of what `TextBox.Text` should start with:

```
sample1
sample2
sample3
```

And end with:

```
sample2
sample1
sample3
```

Comment: `TextBox1.Clear() TextBox1.Lines = myStrings.OrderBy(Function(i) myRnd.Next()).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rng As New Random

'Get the current lines into an array.
Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines

'Randomise the array.
lines = lines.OrderBy(Function(line) rng.NextDouble()).ToArray()

'Put the randomised data back into the control.
TextBox1.Lines = lines
```